# How to bind multiple ViewModels into Expanders using Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mef, caliburn.micro

I have a XAML view that should hold instances of other views and those views should be displayed in a list, each contained in its own `Expander`. I'm using Caliburn.Micro and MEF to set all the components up.

The `ItemsControl` itself works just fine (shows the **content** of the view correctly):

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CursorTools}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

[image: ViewModels in an ItemsControl]

But when I set the `ItemsControl`'s `DataTemplate` to be an `Expander`, the Caliburn no longer "finds" the view for the viewmodel (so the expander is empty):

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CursorTools}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />-->
                <Expander Header="{Binding Path=Title}">
                    <Expander.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Expander.ContentTemplate>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

[image: ViewModels in an Expander]

The problem is that I will have many items and their content will be large enough to fill the screen, so how can I get the `Expander` to set its content properly?

Comment: Expander is a ContentControl. Did you try <Expander Header="{Binding Path=Title}" cal:View.Model="{Binding}" /> (without using a ContentTemplate)?

Comment: @mm8 That was it, thanks! Can you add it as an answer so that I can mark this as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Expander` is actually a `ContentControl` so this should work:

```
<Expander Header="{Binding Path=Title}" cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
```